# Java SQL problems

Tags: java, sql, ms-access, jdbc, jdbc-odbc

i am getting error as following code in java file name javaDAO
try to call a method from jbutton. in my javaDAO file 3 method is define 
1.extablishConnection
2.retriveName
3.CloseConnection
at time of getting userName and password from .access file it gives following errors

```
Dec 8, 2013 11:31:59 AM vuAssignment.JFrame jButton1ActionPerformed
SEVERE: null
java.sql.SQLException: [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver]COUNT field incorrect
at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.createSQLException(JdbcOdbc.java:6957)
at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.standardError(JdbcOdbc.java:7114)
at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.SQLExecute(JdbcOdbc.java:3149)
    at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcPreparedStatement.execute
                                            (JdbcOdbcPreparedStatement.java:216)
    at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcPreparedStatement.executeQuery
                                             (JdbcOdbcPreparedStatement.java:91)
at vuAssignment.javaDAO.retrieveName(javaDAO.java:33)
at vuAssignment.JFrame.jButton1ActionPerformed(JFrame.java:139)
```

Code in javaDAO file is which is call by main method in JFrame.java in netbeans IDE

```
  //method to establish connection
 private void establishConnection() throws ClassNotFoundException,SQLException{
 String driver = "sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver";
 String url = "jdbc:odbc:ProductDb";
 Class.forName(driver);
 con = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
  }
   // method to call query
 public void retrieveName(String pName,String pWord) throws 
 ClassNotFoundException,SQLException{
 String user1= "";
 String pass1 = "";
 String sql  = "SELECT * FROM admin where userName= ? && password= ?";
 PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement(sql);
 ResultSet res = stmt.executeQuery();
        while (res.next()) {
            user1 = res.getString("userName");
            pass1 = res.getString("password");
        }
        if (pName.equals(user1) && pWord.equals(pass1)) 
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"correct");
        else
         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"incorrect");
```

Answer (score 3):

I believe you are confused in using `PreparedStatement` and `ResultSet`. SQL query parameters are not set before executing the query. You need to set userName and password like

```
String sql  = "SELECT * FROM admin where userName= ? && password= ?";
 PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement(sql);
//you need the set the parameters
 stmt.setString(1,userName);
 stmt.setString(2,password);
 //the result set will contain the column values of your query            
 ResultSet res = stmt.executeQuery();
        while (res.next()) {
            //to get the value of the first col
            user1 = res.getString(column1_name);
            //to get the value of the second col
            pass1 = res.getString(column2_name);
        }
```

Hope this helps, Please read the documentation of [PreparedStatement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html) and [ResultSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html)

Comment: Two other problems that I can see: **(1)** The query should use `AND` instead of `&&` in the WHERE clause. **(2)** `PASSWORD` is a [reserved word](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/248738) in Access SQL and should be enclosed in square brackets: `[password]`.

Comment: Yes, I couldn't find the && problem. nice catch! I couldn't know the second one is a problem, I learnt it today. Thanks for the information

Answer (score 0):

Check out with your code. Here is something missing.

```
stmt.setString(1,userName);
 stmt.setString(2,password);
```

Put at right place, after the con.prepareStatement.